# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to parse a json into java object. While doing so I'm getting an exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap". Somehow sometimes this code is working fine. Here is code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;

public class Preference3 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString1 = "{\"ca\":{\"industry\":[{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/financial\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/asset-management\",\"type\":\"checked\"}]},\"fr\":{\"country\":[{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/italy\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/switzerland\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/sweden\",\"type\":\"checked\"}],\"services\":[{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/technology\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/technology/technology-media\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/technology/media\",\"type\":\"checked\"},{\"path\":\"/abc/global/choice/in/technology/telecommunications\",\"type\":\"checked\"}]}}";
        
        Map<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, List>> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString1, LinkedTreeMap.class);
        for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedTreeMap<String, List>> letterEntry : map.entrySet()) {
            String territory = letterEntry.getKey();
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, List> nameEntry : letterEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
            String preferenceType = nameEntry.getKey();
            JsonArray preferenceElements = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree(nameEntry.getValue());
            for (JsonElement preferenceElement : preferenceElements) {
                JsonObject preferenceObj = preferenceElement.getAsJsonObject();
                String preferencePath = preferenceObj.get("path").getAsString();
                    System.out.println(preferencePath);
            }
            }
        }
    }}
```

Is there any other better way to parse this json. I have gone through some blogs but didn't find any other solution and was not able to directly adapt it to any pojo. Kindly help

Comment: what are property `ca` and `fr`, those are dynamic or will remain same?

Comment: dynamic properties

Comment: Is there any static property in json which will remain same or all are dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the exception (aren't there any errata? -- I'm wondering why class A can't be cast to class A when using the same class loader). Also please don't mix deserialization (mapped to a map or a plain object) and `JsonElement` subclasses. If you do, then you have to use proper *types* and *tell* Gson to use them. I would also strongly recommend not stick to concrete classes, especially if they are in internal packages -- they may change in any release breaking your code completely. Stick to interfaces.

> Is there any other better way to parse this json.

Both yes and no. Gson is more of a JSON parsing/writing and serialization/deserialization. What you described if the question is close to how it is typically done in Gson that is just not a JSON-query library.

> I have gone through some blogs but didn't find any other solution and was not able to directly adapt it to any pojo.

You got to use maps unless you know the all the keys and make sure you can describe them in DTO.

Here are some better ways of querying your JSON for the `path` strings:

```java
private static final Iterable<String> expected = ImmutableList.of(
        "/abc/global/choice/in/financial",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/asset-management",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/italy",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/switzerland",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/country/europe/sweden",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/technology",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/technology/technology-media",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/technology/media",
        "/abc/global/choice/in/technology/telecommunications"
);
```

You can use load entire JSON document into memory with the `JsonParser` class. In does not use deserialization and mapping straregies therefore it's probably the quickest and the most robust and native way to represent *any* JSON element using Gson `JsonElement` and its subclasses. Note that deserialization and `Map` do not appear here.

```java
@Test
public void testWithJsonTree()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(openJsonInputStream())) ) {
        final JsonElement jsonTree = JsonParser.parseReader(jsonReader);
        final Collection<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> letterEntry : jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().entrySet() ) {
            for ( final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> nameEntry : letterEntry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().entrySet() ) {
                for ( final JsonElement preferenceElement : nameEntry.getValue().getAsJsonArray() ) {
                    final String preferencePath = preferenceElement.getAsJsonObject().get("path").getAsString();
                    actual.add(preferencePath);
                }
            }
        }
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, actual);
    }
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(openJsonInputStream())) ) {
        final JsonElement jsonTree = JsonParser.parseReader(jsonReader);
        final Iterable<String> actual = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(letterEntry -> letterEntry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().entrySet().stream()
                        .flatMap(nameEntry -> StreamSupport.stream(nameEntry.getValue().getAsJsonArray().spliterator(), false))
                        .map(preferenceElement -> preferenceElement.getAsJsonObject()
                                .get("path")
                                .getAsString()
                        )
                )
                .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

You can tell Gson *concrete* type of the JSON document if you're going to deserialize it. Note that raw Map and List may not work properly because of lacking correct parameterization. The most easy and type-safe way in compile time is describing a type token and make `javac` verify if type parameters are safe and match generic type signatures. Of course you can use other `Type` or `ParameterizedType` implementations, but this seems to be almost perfect (except the fact that every type token definition creates a new class (those `...$1.class`, and so on)).

```java
private static final TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>> elementMapTypeToken
        = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>>>() {};

private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .disableInnerClassSerialization()
        .create();

@Test
public void testWithDynamicMapping()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(openJsonInputStream())) ) {
        final Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>> map = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, elementMapTypeToken.getType());
        final Iterable<String> actual = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(letterEntry -> letterEntry.getValue().values().stream())
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(preference -> preference.get("path"))
                .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

If loading entire JSON document into memory may be memory-consuming and resource/time expensive, you can use streaming and simply read the JSON token by token grafting only what you need. Of course, it may look too hard to implement, but sometimes there is no other way (such approach can also handle infinite streams, by the way). This is the fastest way that can be also combined with deserialization (the `Gson.fromJson(...)` family of methods) to pick more complex values, not simple ones only.

```java
@Test
public void testWithStreaming()
        throws IOException {
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(openJsonInputStream())) ) {
        jsonReader.beginObject();
        final Collection<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
        while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
            jsonReader.nextName();
            jsonReader.beginObject();
            while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                jsonReader.nextName();
                jsonReader.beginArray();
                while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                    jsonReader.beginObject();
                    while ( jsonReader.hasNext() ) {
                        final String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                        switch ( name ) {
                        case "path":
                            actual.add(jsonReader.nextString());
                            break;
                        default:
                            jsonReader.skipValue();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    jsonReader.endObject();
                }
                jsonReader.endArray();
            }
            jsonReader.endObject();
        }
        jsonReader.endObject();
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

And, finally, you can also use a querying library, say JsonPath, that can convert a simple DSL describing a JSON path and traverse the JSON document all itself. I'm not sure how memory and time consuming this approach is, but I guess it is pretty far from being the most optiomal, but it's extremely simple because of the DSL.

```java
private static final Configuration jsonPathConfiguration = Configuration.builder()
        .jsonProvider(new GsonJsonProvider(gson))
        .mappingProvider(new GsonMappingProvider(gson))
        .build();

@Test
public void testWithJsonPath()
        throws IOException {
    final ParseContext parseContext = JsonPath.using(jsonPathConfiguration);
    try ( final InputStream inputStream = openJsonInputStream() ) {
        final DocumentContext documentContext = parseContext.parse(inputStream);
        final Iterable<String> actual = StreamSupport.stream(documentContext.read("$.*.*.*.path", JsonArray.class).spliterator(), false)
                .map(JsonElement::getAsString)
                .collect(ImmutableList.toImmutableList());
        Assertions.assertIterableEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

I also put your JSON into a resource and read it using a custom `openJsonInputStream()` to keep away heavy JSON from the code.

```java
private static InputStream openJsonInputStream() {
    return PreferenceTest.class.getResourceAsStream("preferences.json");
}
```